# How to fix that shining buttons issue after compiling in Unity Canvas

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, button, canvas, unity-ui

I'm using some simple buttons in canvas in a 2D game, there is no light or i don't do anything via code for brightness of button. Buttons are shows normally in scene view, but these are shining in game view like putting a lights on them.  What's the reason for this? How can i solve? You can see that what i mean on image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L09kB.jpg

I checked image attributes of buttons and camera render settings but didn't found anything.

Comment: Your screenshot url only shows "Forbidden".

Comment: Sorry for that, the site I used to upload images was only active in my own country. I changed the link.

Comment: @frankhermes change ur VPN location it goes through here lol.

Comment: @BatuhanArtan its because they have a gradient on them to give that effect, if you want a matte finish you will need to change the sprite being used on the buttons.

Comment: @akaBase thank you for your answering, If the reason was shader, then why theese shader rendering normally in scene view ? And the shaders was render normally also in game view. but i just write some codes that irrelevant with sprites, the sprites began shining.

Comment: Ok i solved, i changed Rendering color space Gamma to Linear in Player Settings >  Other Settings > Rendering